# iptables разрешить только ftp

Tags: iptables

Защита на лабу, разрешить ftp, остальное нет.

Нагуглил такое для http / ftp:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,ACK SYN -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
# iptables -A INPUT -o eth1 -p tcp -j DROP
```

Блокируется все, не пропускает ни http, ни ftp
Помогите, пожалуйста.

И как проверить пропуск ftp? Если в браузере/консоли начать тянуть файл по ссылке ftp://.... то будет использовать же ftp протокол?

Comment: ftp использует диапазон портов для обратной связи (команда port)

Comment: ftp требует авторизацию. Будет, но не все сервера поддерживают ftp без авторизации, а некоторые не поддерживают браузер, а работают только через командную строчку. Авторизация `ftp:login:passw@addr`по-моему

Comment: Дак то что я написал реально сделать? Ограничить все, кроме фтп.